# HTML elements rendering with sizes that don't match the CSS declarations

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand why my HTML elements render in sizes that don't match what is specified by my CSS. As an example I have this declaration in my CSS:

```
.productselectorslist > div { border-bottom-width: 1px;}
```

However, when I look at the element in the browser dev tools when the element renders in Google Chrome it shows:

```
border-bottom-width: 1.1111111640930176px;
```

This sort of size difference is all over the place in the rendered code. It appears like it only starts in the DOM once I start including borders. Once that happens virtually every element has unusual sizes that don't match what I specified in the CSS.

How can I fix all the sizes to always be integers?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109361

Comment: when did you get the impression anything viewed through a browser had any integer sized pixels? welcome to the real world, where browsers, zoom levels and pixels per inches vary a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you zoom out to 90%.

The border is still rendered as a whole pixel while the "logical pixels" are smaller than a whole pixel. The style is adjusted to 1/0.90 = 1.111111 so that it becomes a whole pixel when scaled down.

Answer (score -1):

Although I can't think of any reasons why your borders would render in different sizes, one way of dealing with this issue would be to give a `!important` at the end of your code.

Now this is a work around, and by no means ideal, it might just resolve your issue for the time being.

```
div#test{
border-bottom-width: 1.1111111640930176px !important;
}
```